# How to call flow in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I need to run/call a flow in lightning component.i am getting the below error message :

Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [[object Object]]
Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.interaction.runtime.components.controllers.FlowRuntimeController/ACTION$runInterview

Lightning component code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<div>

<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"  />
</div></aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
init : function (component,event) {
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
     var inputVariables = [
        {
            name : "IDFrecordID",
            type : "Text",
            value : component.get("v.recordId")

        }

    ];
     flow.startFlow("Disclosure_Review_V21",inputVariables);


},})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the following

1. Your flow has an input variable created named "IDFrecordID".
2. Also you can try using flowDataType datatype or use "String" in type  variable as below

   ```
    var inputVariables = [
      {
       name : "IDFrecordID",
       type : "flowDataType",
       value : component.get("v.recordId")

     }
   ];
   ```

Comment: flowdatatype is text only.

Comment: Try with String then because I have never used or seen examples with type as Text ?

Comment: Also it's possible your flow itself is failing to execute and failing at run time

Comment: Its working flowdatatype changed to string.Thanks

Comment: Please mark is as answered if it helped .